# Why when getting the children of object it's not showing more depth levels but only the first level?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the original code and it was working but no matter what object i dragged over to the variable transform into the field "Transform to get childs" it was showing all the objects and each object all levels.

but now i want that it will display only the fragged object childs levels and not all the objects in the hierarchy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetChildsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    public Transform transform;
    List<Transform> allChildren = new List<Transform>();
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    Vector2 scrollPos;

    [MenuItem("Get Childs/Get")]
    static void Init()
    {
        GetChildsEditorWindow window = (GetChildsEditorWindow)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(GetChildsEditorWindow), false, "Get Childs");
        window.Show();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Space(20);
        transform = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Transform to get childs", transform, typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Start"))
        {
            allChildren = new List<Transform>();
            ObjectLevel(transform);

            int count = transform.childCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Transform>().Length; i++)
            {
                var t = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Transform>()[i];
                var level = ObjectLevel(t);
                names.Add(" Level " + level.ToString());
                allChildren.Add(t);
            }
        }

        if (allChildren != null && allChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            scrollPos =
                EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(400), GUILayout.Height(400));
            for (int i = 0; i < allChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                allChildren[i] = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(names[i], allChildren[i], typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
    }

    public static int ObjectLevel(Transform current, int level = 0)
    {
        if (current.parent) return ObjectLevel(current.parent, ++level);

        return level;
    }
}
```

I tried to change this two lines : From :

```
for (int i = 0; i < GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Transform>().Length; i++)
            {
                var t = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Transform>()[i];
```

To :

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var t = transform.GetChild(i);
```

but then when i drag a gameobject it's showing only one level even if there are more depth levels.

Comment: Because the child of any given transform has only 1 level of children. Any further levels are children of its children etc

Answer (score 0):

working

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetChildsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    public Transform transform;

    private List<Transform> allChildren = new List<Transform>();
    private List<string> names = new List<string>();
    private Vector2 scrollPos;

    [MenuItem("Get Childs/Get")]
    static void Init()
    {
        GetChildsEditorWindow window = (GetChildsEditorWindow)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(GetChildsEditorWindow), false, "Get Childs");
        window.Show();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Space(20);
        transform = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Transform to get childs", transform, typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Start"))
        {
            allChildren = new List<Transform>();
            ObjectLevel(transform);

            allChildren = transform.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().ToList();

            foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
            {
                var level = ObjectLevel(child);//t);
                names.Add(" Level " + level.ToString());
            }
        }

        if (allChildren != null && allChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            scrollPos =
                EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(400), GUILayout.Height(400));
            for (int i = 0; i < allChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                allChildren[i] = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(names[i], allChildren[i], typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
    }

    public static int ObjectLevel(Transform current, int level = 0)
    {
        if (current.parent) return ObjectLevel(current.parent, ++level);

        return level;
    }
}
```